# spring 2.5 hibernate mysql - two databases transaction

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

My application is a spring 2.5 Hibernate application connected to a mysql database (database name=mydb). The application is hosted on Tomcat 6 - running on java 6. I have a use case where an admin can edit user's profile. I am planning to store the history of these edits in a separate database (on the same mysql server - database namne= archivedb). In this case the edit user functionality spans over two databases in the same mysql database. Do I need to use JTA transaction. IF JTA, which implementation is the best one . I prefer open source one.

Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good [article](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) on springsource about this. Note however, that it's for Spring 3.0 (as the example uses java-based configuration), but you can most likely transform it to an annotation/xml based setup for Spring 2.5.

The key here is that you use Spring's JtaTransactionManager to delegate to an embedded XA transaction manager. The article uses **Atomikos**, which is one open-source embedded XA transaction manager (see the section "Using Embeddable Transaction Managers").

As you can see, it's not that complicated, Spring does a lot of the abstraction for you. However, it does a a fair bit of complexity to your solution so I would do another iteration of your architecture and evaluate if the benefit of distributed (XA) transaction support merits the extra complexity you introduce. Maybe you don't really need full XA/two-phase commit transactions for just this one use-case?

Comment: Pap,
  Thanks for the quick answer.. I agee with you wheather we need this complexity for a functionality like this. "so I would do another iteration of your architecture and evaluate" - Do you have any better options ?

Comment: @santhosh Evaluate if writing the history is critical enough that it has to happen in the same transaction or if the history can be written within the scope of it's own transaction, after the first edit has been successfully committed. Maybe the small risk of data inconsistency is an acceptable tradeoff for reduced complexity. Alternatively, store the history data in the same database. That way you get rid of the problem completely. You don't need to create complexity just for complexity's sake.